# First global variable not being found in function, causing error. Second global variable does not cause an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Attempting to make an updateable scoreboard companion program for a game with friends. Very new to programing so for learning/first-steps/troubleshooting, set a button that contains the players name, a label that shows their point total, and a checkbox that can be selected depending on the desired point increase. Once the desired point increase is selected, the player's button can be pressed, and the score should be updated. Once the code works, I can expand on the number of player buttons, scores shown and checkboxes. Issue I have encountered is the variable (score1) seems to be an "unresolved reference" (error shown in PyCharm) by the function I have made (score_sum), while another variable (score_update) does not cause an error.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

score1 = IntVar()

score_update = IntVar()


def score_sum():
    if score_update == 1:
        newscore = score1 + 1
        score1 = newscore
    else:
        print("No points scored.")


playername = Button(root, text="Player Name", command=score_sum)
playername.pack()

playerscore = Label(root, textvariable=score1)
playerscore.pack()

plusone = Checkbutton(root, text="1 point", variable=score_update, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
plusone.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Started writing this line-by-line, knowing what I wanted the final code to look like before troubleshooting. Once the error was encountered deleted the line hoping that it would clear the error. Since I had left PyCharm open overnight, tried closing and reopening in desperate hopes the error would clear. Not sure what to change since one variable works while another does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a global variable in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/how-to-use-a-global-variable-in-a-function)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat their problem isn't actually related to using global variables. OP is just misusing tkinter's `IntVar()`s unintentionally

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Unfortunately, no. Since both variables are in the module level (not indented into another layer like the variable "newscore" ), aren't they global by default and therefore no global keyword needed? Very new, so my nomenclature may not be correct.

Comment: You're technically correct, in that those variables are defined in the global scope, but that's not why you're having trouble modifying them.

Comment: @JRiggles Do yoyu have a good reference to better use IntVar()? I have tried to use python help docs, but I get lost in the long instructions trying to absorb it all.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Read the question I linked. Although in this case @JRiggles is correct. (I'm not an SME on tkinter and only opened this question due to the title)

Comment: @self_taught_idiot - When you assign a variable inside of a function, python assumes that it is a local variable, unique to that one call of the function. This is python's shortcut that means you don't have to declare variables in the common case. If you really did want to _assign_ to the global variable, you need to declare that with the `global` keyword. In this case, because its a tkinter `IntVar`, different rules apply as noted in the answers.

Comment: @jriggles - No, that statement is not technically correct. `global` is used in a function to change python's default behavior of making assigned-variables local. Simply having a variable in the module's namespace (that is, "global") does not mean that functions in that module will assign to it automatically.

Comment: @self_taught_idiot all you really need to know for most use cases is that the tkinter "variable" classes, like `IntVar`, `StringVar` etc., have `get` and `set` methods. You'll use those methods to read or write to these objects. So if I declare `foo = tk.StringVar(value='default value!')` I can read it a la `print(foo.get())  # => default value!`, or write to it (modify it) via `foo.set('new value')`

Comment: It seems that when trying to use .get earlier and declaring it not usable in the scenario, i was not using .set properly. I appologize for not mentioning that earlier, but thank you everyone for the information you have given me in response to my problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I only meant that those variables were declared in the global scope - I didn't mean to imply that they could be modified by OP's function as-written. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: To shed some light on the reason for these differences: `IntVar()` creates an **object** which you assign to a variable. Later instead of modifying the variable by assigning another value to it you modify the object to change the data it contains.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Exactly! Well said

Comment: Just FYI, the need for `IntVar` in the first place is due to the difference in semantics between Python and Tcl (the language for which Tk was originally written). In Tcl, would write `$score1` to get the *value* of `score1`, so a command like `label $root -textvariable score1` would use the *name* of the global variable alone to tell `label` which variable to update. In Python, variables aren't "things" in and of themselves: names are just aliases for values, so you need an entirely separate object to represent the idea of "modify this variable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't related to global variables, but rather with how you're handling the two `IntVar`s. When you do this:

```
score1 = IntVar()
```

you're creating an *instance* of a tkinter `IntVar` object and storing that in the variable you've called `score1`. Because of that, when you then do something like

```
score1 = newscore
```

you're *replacing* that `IntVar` object with whatever `newscore` happens to be.

Instead, you need to use their dedicated `get` and `set` methods like so:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

score1 = IntVar()
score_update = IntVar()


def score_sum():
    # use 'get' to query the existing value(s)
    if score_update.get() == 1:
        newscore = score1.get() + 1
        # use 'set' to update the IntVar with a new value
        score1.set(newscore)
    else:
        print("No points scored.")


playername = Button(root, text="Player Name", command=score_sum)
playername.pack()

playerscore = Label(root, textvariable=score1)
playerscore.pack()

plusone = Checkbutton(root, text="1 point", variable=score_update, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
plusone.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Using `get` and `set` like this allows you to read/write the value that's stored within those `IntVar` instances, and in turn allows your other tkinter widgets to interact with those values appropriately.

And for what it's worth, the other tkinter variable classes, `StringVar`, `BooleanVar`, etc., all behave similarly

Comment: I would do this `if score_update.get():` instead of this `if score_update.get() == 1:`

Comment: @toyotaSupra I would too, but I wanted to keep this close to OP's original code. I also wouldn't use an `IntVar` for a Boolean value

Comment: those objects 100% act like normal python objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess I meant "you can't just assign a value to them like you would do with a typical variable" - will edit to clarify. (E: done, hopefully that's better/clearer)

Comment: there is nothing atypical about it. It is a typical variable referring to a typical python object. Of course you can assign to a variable that happens to be referring to an `IntVar` object, in exactly the same way you can assign to a variable that is referring to an `int` object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How would you put it then? My only point was that you can't use something like `score = IntVar()` followed by `score += 5` and expect it to work as intended, and that these behave "differently" from what a beginner might expect when working with something they think is just a "variable". I understand that these are just plain old objects. I'm not saying this behavior is atypical for Python, I'm saying that things like `IntVar` are different from what OP might be used to and need to be worked with accordingly.

Comment: @JRiggles I would say that `IntVar` objects expose methods to access and modify internal values, and you should use those if you want to access or modify internal values.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is my current answer clear enough or do you think I need to edit it further?

Comment: yeah I think the current state of it is very clear

Comment: @JRiggles Thank you very much for assisting me with my question.

Answer (score 1):

The `IntVar` is not a direct variable you can read and write a int to.

You must use the functions `.get()` to get the int value, and `.set(23)` to set the variable to an int (here 23).

`score1 + 1` becomes `score1.get() + 1`

and

`score1 = newscore` becomes `score1.set(newscore)`

Docs on `IntVar` https://tkdocs.com/pyref/intvar.html